# How to generate Perlin Noise for materials

Tags: materials, procedural

I want to generate something like this in the shader editor: [image]

However, I can only find standard noise that I can't work with. How can I generate Perlin Noise?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, Noise Texture _is_ Perlin

Answer (score 4):

You have set the *Type* to "Hard", if you set it back to the default "Soft" you will see it's the regular *Noise Texture*, compare it to this article [Wikipedia: Perlin noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise).

If you want to achieve a look like "Hard" you have to tweak the distribution with a *Color Ramp*, here's a simple try on it:

[image]

Comment: The separation texture/material in blender is just bizarre and unintuitive though, but I imagine "textures" only exist for historical reasons? or is it possible to plug a texture into a material?

Comment: I'm no expert for this, but since these textures are called "Legacy Textures" in the Blender manual I would agree they are there for historical. However, if you want to use textures with the _Displacement_ modifier or for distribution of particles or smoke emission, you still have to use them. What me bothers sometimes is that I can't make such a texture I use for displacement also visible on the mesh directly... I can only see how it displaces the mesh which is of course limited by the amount of mesh detail.